# How to Disable Download and Export Notebook Button in the JupyterHub running on a Docker Container

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

I have a Jupyterhub running on a docker container. I want to restrict notebook Download/Export. How can i do that?